# Why does the OpenSSL repository use the git protocol?

Tags: git, security, openssl

At [OpenSSL/gitrepo](https://www.openssl.org/source/gitrepo.html) they specify that the OpenSSL repository only supports the git protocol (unlike the GitHub clone), however, the git protocol [supports no server authentication](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

Is there any guarantee that I am cloning from the right server? (besides maybe checking https://www.openssl.org). I would expect a security library to use secure methods everywhere.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols says that the Git protocol is undesirable for developers because they cannot be authenticated, but that's OK for read-only access, which implies that there's some form of server authentication and data integrity behind for obvious security reasons. So, who's right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also clone the GitHub mirror repository [`github.com/openssl/openssl`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) (which does support SSH/HTTPS protocol)

You can then add `git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git` as an upstream repo

```
cd /path/to/clone/repo
git remote add upstream git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git
git fetch upstream
```

You can then compare `master` and `upstream/master` to check they do match.